# Adding error message to parameter if seperate derived multivalue parameter is empty using ArcGIS tool validation?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, python-script-tool, tool-validation

I have three tool parameters;

1. an input point feature class,
2. a (multivalue) list of fields derived from the input feature class and
3. an output file location to export to Excel.

I have filtered the fields derived from the feature so only Short, Long, Float, Double, Text and Date types are accepted. I would like to set the tool validation so that if a point feature class is selected that doesn't contain any fields of said types, an error message will show by the input point feature class parameter. The below code shows where I am at currently however does not present an error message.

```
  def updateMessages(self):
"""Modify the messages created by internal validation for each tool
parameter.  This method is called after internal validation."""

if self.params[0].altered and str(self.params[0].value) != "":
  if not self.params[1].value:
    self.params[0].setErrorMessage("The selected feature class does not have any fields. Please check and try again.")
  else:
    self.params[0].clearMessage()
return
```

Comment: I've done some fiddling around with tool validation and your example, the clue might lay in that `self.params[1].value` is not an empty string, just an empty value, so comparing it with `""` will yield `False`. Another thing is that I never got the error messages printed to the dialog using the `updateParameters` function. Using the `updateMessages` function it worked, but now they never cleared.

Comment: Thanks Menno. I´ve still not found a solution as I don´t know how the multivalue list works in the validation script. I´ll keep trying and post a solution if I come across one.

Comment: To help on this one I think we need you to provide all the code for a simple test tool that illustrates what you are trying to do and where you are stuck.