# How apply error messages to a python toolbox that prevent my tool from running with bad parameters?

Tags: python, arcpy, python-toolbox

This is a continuation of my question here: [Point and Polyline](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/143295/how-can-i-use-updateparameters-to-handle-both-points-and-polyline-feature-layers) I tried making this question easier to follow.

My tool accepts two main parameters - a continuous centerline and a table (or a feature class with an attribute table) with polyline features including route ID and measures. If the user chooses a table, I cannot check to see if the table has polylines. I'm going to trust that they are loading the correct data. However, I CAN check to see if the feature class is a polyline or not.

I have tried to do this in updateParameter with a filter. I think I have the wrong idea of how it works though:

```
def updateParameters(self, parameters):
    """
    I am not convinced that this even needs to be here. I've considered using a 
    checkbox instead.
    """
    if parameters[2].altered and parameters[2].hasBeenValidated:
        if parameters[2].dataType == 'Feature':
            parameters[2].filter.list = 'Polyline'
    return
```

In my unit testing, I've been able to select a point feature and it fails (good). When I run this in ArcMap, it accepts points (bad) and runs without errors. I want to be able to have an error message appear in the toolbox window and prevent the user from clicking ok.

My updateMessages looks like this:

```
def updateMessages(self, parameters):
    """
    For instances where a feature class is inputted for param2 and it is a point feature class
    The messaging should prevent the tool from running. 
    """
    # Error in parsing arguments for Describe
    if parameters[0].altered and parameters[0].hasBeenValidated:
        desc = arcpy.Describe(parameters[0].valueAsText)
        if desc.shapeType not in 'Polyline':
            arcpy.AddError("{0} has the wrong data type.")
            raise arcpy.ExecuteError
    if parameters[2].altered and parameters[2].hasBeenValidated:
        desc = arcpy.Describe(parameters[2].valueAsText)
        if desc.datatype == 'Feature' and desc.shapeType not in 'Polyline':
            arcpy.AddError("{2} has the wrong data type.")
            raise arcpy.ExecuteError
    return
```

I took half of this code straight from ESRI's documentation [Writing Messages in Scripts](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00150000000p000000)

I might as well show you the getParameterInfo so you have the whole picture:

```
def getParameterInfo(self):
    """
    Define parameter definitions
    """
    params = list()
    param0 = arcpy.Parameter(displayName="Centerline Layer",
                                       name="param0",
                                       datatype="GPFeatureLayer",
                                       parameterType="Required",
                                       direction="Input")
    param0.filter.list = ['Polyline']
    params.append(param0)
    param1 = arcpy.Parameter(displayName="Centerline ID",
                                                      name="param1",
                                                      datatype="Field",
                                                      parameterType="Required",
                                                      direction="Input")
    param1.parameterDependencies = [param0.name]
    params.append(param1)

    param2 = arcpy.Parameter(displayName="Polyline Compare",
                                           name="param2",
                                           datatype="GPTableView", # table or attribute table
                                           parameterType="Required",
                                           direction="Input")
    params.append(param2)

    param3 = arcpy.Parameter(displayName="Polyline Compare ID",
                                                          name="param3",
                                                          datatype="Field",
                                                          parameterType="Required",
                                                          direction="Input")
    param3.parameterDependencies = [param2.name]
    params.append(param3)

    return params
```

As you can see, the Centerline (param0) was easier to do. I just included it in the code so that it would still create an error if it is called. I could put a error statement in the execute method like this:

```
desc = arcpy.Describe(param0.value)
if desc.shapeType != 'Polyline':
    raise arcpy.ExecuteError("Incorrect Data Type: Select a polyline.")
desc = arcpy.Describe(param2.value)
if desc.dataType == 'Feature Class' and desc.shapeType != 'Polyline':
    raise arcpy.ExecuteError("Incorrect Data Type: Select a polyline.")
```

Right now the error messages just do not appear. I have looked through every relevant post tagged python toolbox. [This one needs an answer too!](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/120238/adding-error-message-to-parameter-if-seperate-derived-multivalue-parameter-is-em) Anyone in the Stack able to help with this one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing to remember, all actions that involve the parameter should be off the parameter object; so use `parameters[n].setErrorMessage(msg)` instead of `arcpy.AddError(msg)`. `AddError` is used to add error messages into the tool execution messages, `setErrorMessage` is to add an error to the parameter that will block the tool from executing. So you also don't need to raise any exceptions.

A couple other issues, and something like the below should do what you've described.

```
def updateMessages(self, parameters):
    """Modify the messages created by internal validation for each tool
    parameter.  This method is called after internal validation."""

    polyline_compare = parameters[2].valueAsText
    if polyline_compare:
        desc = arcpy.Describe(polyline_compare)
        if desc.datasettype in ['FeatureClass', 'FeatureLayer']:
            if desc.shapetype != 'Polyline':
                parameters[2].setErrorMessage('Only polylines and tables are accepted')

    return
```

Comment: I am getting the error message! I would love to have a training on how to use arcpy error messages side by side with how to use Python error messages. In this case, I can take your answer on how to use setErrorMessage properly. Thank you. How was my question in terms of readability? I tend to be verbose...

Comment: @keepaustinbeard. Readability was better than the other one ;)  Thanks for boiling it down.